# Python3 ZMQ, Interrupt function and calling another on each new message received

Tags: python-3.x, zeromq

Here is my problem : I have 2 programs communicating thanks to zmq on an arbitrary tcp port.
When the #1 receives message from #2 he has to call some function.
If #1 receives a message before the current function ends, I'd like #1 to interrupt the current function and call the new one.
I tried to use threading.Event to interrupt function.
I don't know if zmq is the right option for my needs or if the socket types fine.

To simplify I show the simplest version possible,here is what I tried :
p1.py

```
import zmq
from threading import Event

port_p2 = "6655"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port_p2)
print("port 6655")

__exit1 = Event()
__exit2 = Event()


def action1():
    __exit1.clear()
    __exit2.set()
    while not __exit1.is_set():
        for i in range(1, 20):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)
        __exit1.set()


def action2():
    __exit2.clear()
    __exit1.set()
    while not __exit2.is_set():
        for i in range(1, 20):
            print(i * 100)
            time.sleep(1)
        __exit2.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                string = socket.recv(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
                # message received, process it
                string = str(string, 'utf-8')
                if "Action1" in string:
                    action1()
                if "Action2" in string:
                    action2()
            except zmq.Again as e:
                # No messages waiting to be processed
                pass
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print("exit")
```

and p2.py

```
import time
import random

port_p1 = "6655"
context = zmq.Context()
socket_p1 = context.socket(zmq.PAIR)
socket_p1.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port_p1)
print("port 6655")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    while True:
        i = random.choice(range(1, 10))
        print(i)
        try:
            if random.choice([True, False]):
                print("Action 1")
                socket_p1.send(b'Action1')
            else:
                socket_p1.send(b'Action2')
                print("Action 2")
        except zmq.Again as e:
            pass
        time.sleep(i)
```

For my purpose I didn't want / can't use system signals

I'd appreciate any input and don't hesitate to ask for precision, I have to confess that I had trouble writing this down.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *…**like #1 to interrupt** the current function…*

Given you have forbidden to use signals, **#1 can but passively signal** (be it over the present ZeroMQ infrastructure or not) **the *function***, not to continue further and return in a pre-mature fashion ( so the `fun()` has to get suitably modified for doing that active re-checking, best in some reasonably granular progressive fashion, regularly checking actively the #1 if did passively signal ( "tell" the `fun()` ) to `RET` early, due to whatever reason and way the #1 had and used to do that ).

The other chance is to extend the already present ZeroMQ infrastructure ( the `Context()`-instance(s) ) with a socket-monitor artillery and make the `fun()` `.connect()`-directly to the socket-monitor resources to actively learn about any new message arriving to #1 ( i.e. autonomously, without #1's initiative ) and deciding to return in a pre-mature fashion, in those cases, where feasible according to your application logic.

For the socket-monitor case, the API documentation has all details needed for implementation, which would otherwise go way beyond the scope of the Stack Overflow post.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. I think I'll rethink my flow because it seems too complicated for my needs